# How to re-rail this pocket door?

Tags: doors

I don't know how, but my bathroom pocket door got de-railed. What is the right way to re-rail this?

Here is a picture of the part of the door:

[image]

And here is a picture of the part of the "frame":

[image]

As you can imagine, it's hard to fit these two pieces together because there is no space to put my fingers/tool. How does one fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very common problem with pocket doors is that after they are installed, trim is added to close up, hide the gap. Sometimes all you can do is to remove one side of the trim.

Try propping up the door at that end to keep it stationary. Bend a steel coat hanger with a few bends to fit up in the groove and use it to slide the roller pin into the slot after moving the locking arm out of the way. you might have to raise or lower the door a bit to get the roller pin to slide into the slot. Close the locking arm.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "trim"?

Comment: @Nobita "trim" is the wood bits that surround the door frame, hiding the edge of the frame and the (usually) unfinished edge of the wall making a nice finished appearance. In your first picture, the trim is the rounded part above the dark gap.

Comment: got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Push the locking mechanism (the white arm) with kitchen knife to the left.

Lift the door and slide it over the bolt coming from the top from left.

Close the locking arm.

Why it derailed?

As far I can see the bolt is not secured with the nut and can loosen. Screw the nut all the way to the top to secure the bolt in the position (with door out of your way) for easy access. That bolt will be used to adjust the hight of the door.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem I have is that when I push the door, the nut on the top slides too, so I can't fit it in.